# Java 7 precise rethrow and legacy code

Tags: java, exception, java-7, rethrow

The more precise rethrow allows to write code that throws the exception really thrown :

```
   public void foo(String bar) throws FirstException, SecondException {
     try{
       // Code that may throw both FirstException and SecondException
     }
     catch (Exception e){
       throw e;
     }
   }
```

Prior to Java 7 you had to write :

```
   public void foo(String bar) throws Exception {
     try{
       // Code that may throw both FirstException and SecondException
     }
     catch (Exception e){
       throw e;
     }
   }
```

**My question**: is there a tool that allows to detect imprecise throw in order to replace "`Exception`" with "`FirstException, SecondException`"?

So far, I have checked that there is no compiler warning in Eclipse. There is no rule in FindBugs or CodePro.

Comment: I suggest you add following sentence to your question: "My target is to ..." So far you have not been given good advice because people have been guessing your goal wrong.

Comment: I think the question is quite clear: In order to update legacy code that was lazily written to throw too broad an exception, is there a tool that finds such code so that it can be updated using the new convenient Java7 syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not a situation for a compiler warning, because the "overly broad" exception is not necessarily a problem: Unless the method is final or private, it defines what kind of exception any subclass implementation can throw. In that case, the wide scope may have been intentional.

Your question would apply equally well for Java pre-7:

```
public void foo(String bar) throws Exception {
    // Code that may throw both FirstException and SecondException
}
```

Here, `throws Exception` could also be considered bad practice (but there are no warnings about it).

Along the same line of argument, note that you will get a compile *error* when you try to catch a (checked) Exception that cannot possibly be thrown, but you can add to the `throws` clause of the method signature all kinds of exceptions that the implementation body does not use.

A tool like FindBugs would be useful though.

---

Update: "Unless the method is final or private" : I have to agree that for private or final methods (and maybe static ones, too) there could be a warning.

Update 2: Even for final methods, you may want to leave your options open to throw more Exceptions in the future without breaking the interface.

Answer (score -2):

Try casting the exception before throw, maybe it will do the trick?

```
public void foo(String bar) throws FirstException, SecondException {
  try{
    // Code that may throw both FirstException and SecondException
  }
  catch (Exception e){
    throw ((e instanceof FirstException) ? (FirstException)e : (SecondException)e);
  }
}
```

BTW, rethrowing the same exception seems rather clumsy thing to me...

Comment: The point is that in Java 7 this is **not** necessary: you can use `throws FirstException, SecondException` **and** use a simple `throw e`.